# FluentAssertions cast type to another on the fly when comparing

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

I'm facing some issues when using ***FluentAssertions*** lib to make a ***equivalency*** check on two ***System.Data*** objects.

I have this scenario:

```
Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Should().BeEquivalentTo(Columns.OfType<DataColumn>(), options => options
                                                                                    .Using<double>(ctx => ((double)ctx.Subject).Should().BeApproximately((double)ctx.Expectation, 0.000000001F))
                                                                                    .WhenTypeIs<double>());
```

***Columns*** object is of ***System.Data.DataColumnCollection*** type

and when I run the test, I got this exception:

```
Expected property Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()[8].DataType to be System.Decimal, but found System.Double.
```

And it's of course self explanatory, I have a type missmatch when comparing (the reason why there is a missmatch is because the expected value is being deserialized from *base 64* and I canno't affect that deserialization at all. It converts some floating point numbers to ***decimal*** and that's why conversion fails.

***My question is***, can I do some overrides of the comparison on the fly (e. g. can I do cast before comparison, or something like that) in order to achieve that comparison doesn't throw the exception.

***I've tried doing this:***

```
Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
       .Should()
       .BeEquivalentTo(Columns.OfType<DataColumn>(), options => options                                                                                                      
                                                     .RespectingDeclaredTypes()                                  
                                                     .Using<decimal>(ctx => (decimal.ToDouble(ctx.Subject)).Should().BeApproximately(decimal.ToDouble(ctx.Expectation), 0.000000001F))
                                                                                                 .WhenTypeIs<decimal>()
                                                                                                    .Using<double>(ctx => ((double)ctx.Subject).Should().BeApproximately((double)ctx.Expectation, 0.000000001F))
                                                                                                    .WhenTypeIs<double>()); //comparing columns for equivalency
```

but it doesn't do the trick.

***Any suggestions how can I overcome this?***

Comment: `DataColumn` only holds metadata, not the values. You would need to override *both* the way the columns are compared (i.e. harmonizing the `DataType`s) and then you'd still need to have more code to compare the actual values (held in `DataRow`s in a `DataTable`, presumably). Overall you're better off *actually* making the data equivalent rather than trying to figure out what has to be a quite complicated way to configure things. An alternative is to write an [`IEquivalencyStep`](https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/#equivalency-assertion-step-by-step) for `DataTable`s.